# input() After conditional statement is met problem

Tags: python

I started learning a few days ago and I've encountered a problem I cant figure out.

Essentially if the input is "yes" I want the code to **stop** however the input tab is still open on for input. I don't know if this is specific to Juypter notebook.

```py
if input() == "yes": 
    print("lovely , now go get them gains!")
else:
    print("ok what do you want to change?\nmilk" , "protein powder" , "snack")
input()
```

Comment: The `input()` prompt would be open because `input()` is called after the `if`/`else` conditionals. You could import the `sys` module and call `sys.exit()` inside the `if` clause if you want somewhat of a quitting functionality.

Comment: Just add four spaces before the last `input()`.

Comment: It is only a indentation problem. If you put last `input` in same block (inside) of `else` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
if input("Enter something: ") == "yes":
    print("lovely , now go get them gains!")
else:
    print("ok what do you want to change?\nmilk" , "protein powder" , "snack")
    input("Enter something: ")
```

Comment: Im still not able to get it to work, I think its not working because of the code I have beneath

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning `input` to a variable. It's better

```py
def function():
    value = input('Type something: ')
    if value == "yes": 
        print("lovely , now go get them gains!")
        quit()
    else:
        print("ok what do you want to change?\nmilk" , "protein powder" , "snack")
        function()
```

Output:
[image: output]